# add custom column with value to returned row object from query wpdb

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, object, row

```
foreach($result as $row) {
     echo $row;
 }
     echoes the object
{
"NDB_No": "20129",
"Ingredient": "Wheat flours, bread, unenriched",
"PolyFat": "0.72",
"Chol": "0",
"Refuse_Pct": "0",
"Instructions": "Δεν Υπάρχουν Οδηγίες",
"Ingredients": "Δεν Υπάρχουν Υλικά",
"Image": "20129_Wheat flours.png"
}
```

**How can i add "somename":"somevalue" at the end of returned result row (row is an object)
from a wpdb query with php?
Thanks in advance guys.**

Answer (score 0):

After some digging for anyone else who is interested:

```
$row->somename = $somevalue;
```

Cheers.